# Archiving, Scheme settings and Code Signing in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in the process of submitting an app to the App Store. I am using Xcode 4.2 (Build 4C151a).

In the build settings I can choose iPhone Distribution for code signing under Release - Any iOS SDK. Then I go to menu Product > Edit Scheme and set the Archive Build configuration to release, Then Product > Archive. The first problem I have is that it builds and says build succeeded but no archive file shows in the Organizer. When I go to the Archive files location through Finder I see that that specific Archive file is Zero Bytes. If I repeat the same thing but change the Archive Build Configuration to Debug under Edit Scheme, the Archive file gets created and shows up in the Organizer. Now comes the second problem, when I choose that just created Archive and hit Share... button and choose iOS App Store Package (.ipa), for Identity, I cannot choose iPhone Distribution (It's gray and it says does not match any valid identity/profile pairs) even though in the Build Setting, it was fine and matched. However, iPhone Developer shows up active under Identity selections. Any help with either or both of these problems is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since Xcode 4.2 is under NDA the question really can n to be answered.  If however a similar question were asked about Xcode 4.1 it could be answered.

Comment: So do you think the problem is that I am using a preview version of Xcode, or may I encounter similar problem in Xcode 4.1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem persisted with downgrading to the last full-version of Xcode. Apparently, I missed some steps when I created the Distribution Provisioning Profile. After creating Distribution Provisioning Profile correctly, everything started to act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit apps to the appstore using beta/developer preview versions of Xcode. In this case, 4.1.1 is the latest public release, via the Mac App Store.

Comment: I've never worked with a developer build such as 4.2, so am unsure if it has left your previous install intact or not. Have a dig in the Developer folder - you'll soon find the answer. 4.1.1 or any previous version of Xcode will allow you to submit your app.

Comment: So basically, since I have iOS 5 on my iPhone, I need the beta version of Xcode to be able to test on the device but still need a full version of Xcode to submit to App Store. Is that right?

Comment: Well, unless you're submitting for iOS 5 if such an option exists, then it may be different. (like when they opened iPad and Mac Appstore submissions... iirc the process was a little different)